# Unit returned by accelerator in iOS

Tags: ios, accelerator

I am doing some calculation by the data returned by the accelerator of iPhone.

```
CMMotionManager *motionManager =[[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
CMDeviceMotion *motionData = motionManager.deviceMotion;
CMAcceleration userAcceleration = motionData.userAcceleration;
.
.
.
double accX = userAcceleration.x;
```

So, what does the value of accX mean? Does it have a unit of meter/sec^2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. From the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAccelerometerData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CMAcceleration

A G is a unit of gravitation force equal to that exerted by the earth’s gravitational field (9.81 m s−2).